# Are there loop holes when using "Manage Content and Structure"?

Tags: content

I had users in the contribute group and they weren't able to perform copy or move from "Manage Content and Structure". I had to grant Manage list permission to this users in order to use "Manage Content and Structure". The manage list permission lets these user manage the list or library which is we are trying to prevent. Users add columns without good practice or a view with 10000 items in return. These are reasons we dont want users to have manage list access.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Disable **SharePoint Server Publishing** and the "Manage Content and Structure" option will be gone from Site Administration. However you can still access Content and Structure Page by appending **_layouts/sitemanager.aspx** in URL.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. that's not the question. The question is I want to grant acces to Manage content and structure so users can copy or move data between libraries. but i dont want to grant user access list level settings which comes with manage content permissions